# Let's draw the Triforce

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

The [Triforce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce) is a fictional artifact in [The Legend of Zelda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda), made of three identical-looking equilateral triangles representing power, wisdom and courage. Several games in the saga include an animation when the three parts finally join together.

The purpose of this challenge is to draw a single 2D frame of such a simplified animation, with a given width for the triangles and a given spacing between the parts.

### Input

The input consists of two integers: a width \$w\ge1\$ and a spacing value \$s\ge0\$.

### Output

The frame has to be drawn according to the following specifications:

```
         /\
        /  \____________ this part is horizontally centered
       /    \
      /______\
                    \___ s empty lines
                    /
   /\          /\
  /  \        /  \______ w+1 backslashes
 /    \      /    \
/______\    /______\
                \_______ 2w underscores
        |__|
          \_____________ 2s spaces
```

In the above example, we have \$w=3\$ and \$s=2\$.

### More examples

\$w=1\$, \$s=0\$:

```
   /\   
  /__\  
 /\  /\ 
/__\/__\
```

\$w=2\$, \$s=0\$:

```
     /\     
    /  \    
   /____\   
  /\    /\  
 /  \  /  \ 
/____\/____\
```

\$w=3\$, \$s=3\$:

```
          /\          
         /  \         
        /    \        
       /______\       



   /\            /\   
  /  \          /  \  
 /    \        /    \ 
/______\      /______\
```

\$w=4\$, \$s=1\$:

```
          /\          
         /  \         
        /    \        
       /      \       
      /________\      

    /\          /\    
   /  \        /  \   
  /    \      /    \  
 /      \    /      \ 
/________\  /________\
```

### Rules

- Trailing spaces on each line are optional.
- Extra leading spaces on each line are not allowed.
- You may output a single extra leading newline and/or a single extra trailing newline.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf).

Answer (score 10):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>197</s> <s>194</s> <s>169</s> <s>167</s> <s>155</s> 144 bytes

```python
w,s=input()
l=['']*(2*-~w+s)
for i in range(-~w):W=w-i;b='/'+'_ '[i<w]*2*i+'\\';l[i::w-~s]=' '*(w+s-~W)+b,' '*W+b+'  '*(W+s)+b
print'\n'.join(l)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcxNDoMgEEDhvadgN8BAm9CdlnOwUNOUpD/TmNGIDemGq1Ndvm/xlt/2ntnVmk3yxMt3k6qZfA8waum0LRmTap7zKkgQi/XOr4fcVbXBZ0td9HAGhJuAnq551E4TwjBAN/XUttmWNHoQoOX@sSUojObIgBFBHB72P8ZmWYk3GBhOn5lYTqrWi3F/)

---

Saved:

- -3 bytes, thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Answer (score 9):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 25 bytes

```
←×_Ｎ↗⊕θ‖Ｍ≔⁺⊕θＮηＣη±η‖ＢＯ⊗⊕θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Xc49D4IwFIXhnV/RON0muOgmkx@LiSIhOhvAC21SSr3ckvDrKyQOyv6cN6dSBVVdYULISFuG3QVrjsVdt9jD6rmKxdk6z6lvSySQUibRFz5crhvFM6gIW7SML3jPIMfaYMVXTdRNmyTa971uLGTG9/Cvl/lYqMkfOzeCikWKTcEI6id68MxItRlvA5IpHJw6X5qptXghkxC20SasB/MB) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
←×_Ｎ
```

Input `w` and draw `w` `_`s.

```
↗⊕θ
```

Draw `w+1` `/`s.

```
‖Ｍ
```

Reflect to complete the first triangle.

```
≔⁺⊕θＮη
```

Input `s` and calculate the offset between the left and middle triangles.

```
Ｃη±η
```

Copy the left triangle to the middle.

```
‖ＢＯ⊗⊕θ
```

Reflect around the middle triangle to complete the triforce.

Comment: Uh, check your math on this. This may be 25 *characters*, but it's 50 to 65 *bytes* (depending on whether you use UTF-16 or UTF-8 representation, respectively).

Comment: My bad; apparently, Charcoal and Canvas have [their own character mappings](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171516/lets-draw-the-triforce#comment414334_171526), which seems a touch silly to me (if you're going to use arbitrary symbols, why not use an existing selection), but whatever.

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley The point of this site is to golf program size. Many languages (there are many, many more than just Canvas & Charcoal) opted for utilizing all 8 bits per byte, since that's a very good way to reach closer to maximum golfiness. The pretty unicode is just for making code easier to read and write (you try programming in C by writing bytecode; we are humans too)

Answer (score 8):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>127</s> 124 bytes

```python
w,s=input()
n=2*-~w+s
while n:n-=1;I=w-n+(n>w)*(w-~s);print' '*n+('  '*(n+s)).join(['/'+I*2*' _'[I>=w]+'\\'][I>w:]*-~(n<=w))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DY0xDsMgDAD3vILNNoRWZUxKdt6QoE6VQlU5qFBZXfJ1ynSnWy7/6n6wa03G4hPnb0Ua2DttTzFlkD29n4ontv42By@WDfIipFHsWWjOn8QVFOjeQXUim0J0eR2JcYUrmKCdBvWANSxeooFtg9hdptgXyHcvRK250f0B)

Answer (score 7):

## [Canvas](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 16 [bytes](https://github.com/dzaima/Canvas/blob/master/files/chartable.md)

```
＋├：⁸╵＼Ｌ_×；∔║ω╋║↕
```

[Try it here!](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjBCJXUyNTFDJXVGRjFBJXUyMDc4JXUyNTc1JXVGRjNDJXVGRjJDXyVENyV1RkYxQiV1MjIxNCV1MjU1MSV1MDNDOSV1MjU0QiV1MjU1MSV1MjE5NQ__,i=NyUwQTA_,v=6)

Explanation:

```
+├                s + w + 2
  :               duplicated (for both X & Y)
   ⁸╵\            w+1 sized diagonal
      L_×         "_"*width of the diagonal
         ;∔       prepended before the diagonal
           ║      palindromize that
            ω     and push the argument of ║ (aka the unpalindromized version)
             ╋    overlap the upside down half-triangle over the upside down triangle at (s+w+2; s+w+2)
              ║   and palindromize the whole thing
               ↕  reverse everything vertically
```

note: in the making of this I fixed a mistake in the code, Without that fix, this would be [18 bytes](https://dzaima.github.io/Canvas/?u=JXVGRjBCJXUyNTFDJXVGRjFBJXUyMDc4JXUyNTc1JXVGRjNDJXVGRjJDXyVENyV1RkYxQiV1MjIxNCV1MjE5NSV1MjE5NSV1MjU1MSV1MDNDOSV1MjU0QiV1MjU1MSV1MjE5NQ__,i=NyUwQTA_,v=6).

Comment: Like [Neil's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171516/lets-draw-the-triforce#comment414332_171518), this may be 16 *characters*, but in Unicode terms, it's either 32 or 44 bytes, depending on which UTF you use. (I considered that it might be representable in a legacy single-byte character set like [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437), but there's no ω or ⁸ available there, so it seems to me you'd have to go with a Unicode transformation format.)

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Canvas uses a custom codepage, as linked in the title of my post. The github wiki for Charcoal contains its codepage too. It's agreed upon on PPCG that it's okay to answer with unicode formatted answers if there's a codepage/converter backing it up.

Comment: Tcsh, okay (though at the point that you're using arbitrary converters, it seems to me that you might as well be writing in a language with full names and measuring a compiled VM bytecode instruction length).

Comment: @StuartP.Bentley Check the Charcoal answers link - it contains human readable code! (so yes, 2 transpilations :p) People here do answer in assembly scoring as machine code, so there's no reason to answer in VMs too

Answer (score 7):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>225</s>, <s>224</s>, <s>214</s>, <s>211</s>, 208 bytes

```r
function(w,s){M=matrix
C=cbind
h=w+1
k=C(apply(m<-diag(h)*60,1,rev)/4,m)
k[row(k)==h&!k]=63
z=rbind(C(a<-M(0,h,h+s),k,a),M(0,s,h*4+2*s),C(k,M(0,h,2*s),k))
z[]=intToUtf8(z+32,T)
apply(z,1,cat,sep='','
')
rm()}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JU67TsNAEOz3L2jwrr1R/FJEka1cpwtVlOJwctzp8EPnIwYjvt3YuBrNaF5@1jLrz7YOtmtx5IF@TtKo4O0XVFK/2fYGRsYkAycVqr7/@MbmuLtZ9Y6G4kPKGfv7g/YlNwTu4rsRHYmY5yd3lUMBk/i1BJfwcXfClA2bZCB2rIhXPrCJyySPF61Cx5vlnzoimC5XsW04d69Bv@CUFDmfCbYf07Jdq8DDvZco4ggiAt8g/c4aM04JNOYbFFysUHJG8x8)

- -1 byte thanks to Giuseppe
- -10 bytes after change of approach
- -3 bytes exploting ASCII code
- -3 bytes thanks to JayCe

Comment: Since I couldn't find anything to add to this... I just renamed variables and also I am suggesting another avenue to return silently... which I am not completely satisfied with TBH. Will keep searching! [TIO](https://tio.run/##JY3LbsIwEEX3/otuyEwyqHkJIYVZRHJ2XtINiIUbcGWJPOq4SSvEt6cEVkfn6upeNxuezU9be9u1MNGAt5F131//xIEb7Z39FRXXn7Y9C8VTlAjJFYzQ7NZnq79AYbiJKSF3GfE9pwYLeXTdBBKZ1epNnniTiZLdMgAV6N36ADEpUtGAJEkjLT6QCvMoDR9ZBZJeladKxKI8nti2ft99eLOFMspS2mMxQvn4rbWn4dJzEFAgAhTfgPfZQEIxCgPpCxllC3JKcP4H)

Comment: oh wait ... `if(F)0` is acceptable for sure and saves one byte. Or even better `rm()` for 3 bytes.

Comment: My suggestion to use `q()` in my first comment is invalid as per [this meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4939/80010)

Comment: @JayCe: great trick using rm() !

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>256</s> <s>248</s> <s>240</s> <s>228</s> <s>199</s> 195  bytes

A longer program, but slightly different approach:

```python
f,b,o='/\ '
O=o*2
w,s=input()
l=f+'__'*w+b
a=l+O*s+l
m=n=[]
p=lambda g:(len(a)-len(g))/2*o+g
for i in range(w):m=m+[p(f+O*i+b)];t=f+O*i+b;n+=p(t+O*(w-i+s)+t),
print'\n'.join(m+[p(l)]+[o]*s+n+[a])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY5BDoIwEEX3PUV37TBVE9xh5gwcABtTImBNO22ghnh6ROPq/7f4Lz@/yyNxvW2j6U0idbpKJVpKVS1Ws5Dn/CoaRKAR1e2mqhV74ShgWy0YRCSmzopMwcX@7uTU6DCwdnD4xgRwqquEkxjTLL30LGfH06BXaCJF7LIed5HHHuyl0L9fGCnrsoNeDx4XwAJG5NlzUVdWx2fyrH/jABa7ZPcnjJ2zsG1nU38A)

---

saved a lot of bytes thanks to ignoring the trailing whitespace, and incorporating some tricks from @ovs
saved even more by defining a variable earlier

Comment: I shall have to fix this tomorrow (it works, but I can do better)

Comment: [218 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7RqsIwEETf@xV5y253VRBfrmG/wR8QpMWm5pJuQhop15/vrejTzHBgZvJffSQ9rqvnnpPYw9VYd5FEyS08S9D8rIDuJaXTcYAFXRRP9naz7UK96yTSpZ0puklUAJv74E2GEc9ZIA4KHe7eMiIejm1yZajPoibTSLnxqZhggprXeSLJ4LeqQD2yq/L1Tt@gbgGWXaAZqSI3uQSt9qp2/5uCwkSQISIjQWo/o4zbKSXoGHFdT/zzDw).

Comment: [216 bytes](https://tio.run/##LY7BbsIwEETv@Qrf7PUakCIuxdpv4AOMhRyVBFfO2kpcReXnQ4CeZuYw86b81Xvmdl1705lM8nAR0p4pY7aLmSly@a0K7IOmwMNNLWAT9SivV6kX7GyghGc9Y7IjMTnfFEph7L6DGE7D/idHVk6lG6sAu5cMAIdWZ69baPo8iSgii8dppBFdUf22FbEDbyv9e8tIRdUtqGUXcQasYJoyRa7ywvKDeJcTeHRZf2B@@8Togod1PZqvJw)

Comment: [fixed byte count.](https://tio.run/##LY5LDsIwDET3PkV2ievwUZcgn4EDlAilgpag1InaoAouXwpiNfMW8zT5Ve5J6mXpbGsT691ZaThxqmqY7cRB8rMYhDePXvqbmREid6QvF13N1ILnSKdqoggDCzcOMkc/tFev@oOJNzEeN9/oEXd1laiHLo0qqCDqfRh4oCabbjUEatEdC//7UYizKSuYeRNoQipoIY9Bij6L3j5SEPMbR3TUJLdeEGq8w2XZ2/0H)

Comment: that was a byproduct from when there was two

Comment: go ahead and edit, on mobile right now

Comment: that would be nice

Answer (score 4):

## [Pascal (FPC)](https://www.freepascal.org/), <s>296</s> 264 bytes

```pascal
const A='/';B='\';var w,s,i:word;u:string;begin read(w,s);u:=StringOfChar('_',2*w);for i:=1to w do writeln(A:w+3+s+w-i,B:i*2-1);writeln(A:w+2+s,u,B);for i:=1to s do writeln;for i:=1to w do writeln(A:w+2-i,B:i*2-1,A:2*(s+w-i)+3,B:i*2-1);write(A,u,B,A:2*s+1,u,B)end.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY2xDoMgFEV/hQ0QbCNuEAftB3To2qShopbEoOFp@XxqWWo7dLnLuTln1tDqMe/nNsZ2crCgusJHrJoKX7F6ao8CB25lmLxRq4TFWzeoezdYh3ynDdkw3UB1SeTcnx7aE3zDXGSBqn7yyMqqWCYUkNnG26UbHallYCUDFnLLG2kzkRdU7aFgwFfefBlgZ/hrFh8rr6XISApRVv60SP1upAuwIvU6Zw4xlki8AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 126 bytes

```ruby
->w,s{(-v=w+1).upto(v){|i|j= ~-i%-~v;$><<[$/*s,$/+' '*(v+s)+t="/#{(j<w ?' ':?_)*j*2}\\".center(w*2+2)+' '*s*2,$/+t*2][0<=>i]}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvdCoMgGADQV4nmSD@zHy83rQcxGWwU1EUbacooe3X3c3vgLOv9HQcZWeNzs2HmpKc1KdaXfWJHtn3cJ5kcbDyzw11RI4RCJZgclTRLMsCOGkKtTMvThifhk/arl/ZGYAIeui4tHv1s@wV74JST/zHAf90C16oSshl1CHFQVV7r@AE)

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 141 bytes

```
\d+
$* 
(?=( *),( *))
¶$1/$`$`\$1$2$2$1/$`$`\
T` `\_`/ *\\(?=.*,)
s`¶(.*),( *)
$1¶$.2$*¶$1
\G(( *)/(  |__)*\\)\2(  )*\1 *¶
$2 $#3$* $#4$* $1¶
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY4xCsMwDEV3nUKQP9iusbHTtXTsBTIKrEA7dOnQduy5coBczJUhCD764r@P3o/v87X2LvcTITC568Vx8HGIp31DyVCooKDaHI4WZZWmmYOIISlETx/dN5cOllAMThVhdJDc3Lhmx/xrzRvlpZqxrbBFCJUxzfYBpvNQo3ufY/0D) Note: Some trailing whitespace in output. Explanation:

```
\d+
$*
```

Convert the inputs into spaces. (The second line ends with a space.)

```
(?=( *),( *))
¶$1/$`$`\$1$2$2$1/$`$`\
```

Create the sides of the bottom two triangles with the appropriate spacing.

```
T` `\_`/ *\\(?=.*,)
```

Fill in the base of the triangles.

```
s`¶(.*),( *)
$1¶$.2$*¶$1
```

Duplicate the triangles with the appropriate vertical spacing.

```
\G(( *)/(  |__)*\\)\2(  )*\1 *¶
$2 $#3$* $#4$* $1¶
```

Convert the upper triangles into a single centred triangle.

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), <s>404</s> 389 bytes

```c
#define p(x)putchar(x);
#define F for
W;S;i;a=32;b=47;c=92;f(w,s){W=w,S=s;F(;w;--w){F(i=W+w+s+1;i--;)p(a)p(b)F(i=w*2;i++-2*W;)p(a)p(c)p(10)}F(i=W+s+1;i--;)p(a)p(b)F(i=0;i++-2*W;)p(95)p(c)F(;s--+1;)p(10)F(w=W;w;--w){F(i=w;i--;)p(a)p(b)F(i=w*2;i++-2*W;)p(a)p(c)F(i=w*2+S*2;i--;)p(a)p(b)F(i=w*2;i++-2*W;)p(a)p(c)p(10)}p(b)F(i=0;i++-2*W;)p(95)p(c)F(i=S*2;i--;)p(a)p(b)F(i=0;i++-2*W;)p(95)p(c)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZGxCoMwEIbn@hSBLokxoLGlyJHVF3DIrFHbDFXRtimIz25jreAgpR0Ojvvvu/@HU@ys1Dju86LUVYEa/CTN/aYuaWs7cJZ5jMq6dSQkoCEVIYdMHE6gRMShxMbrSC@F8RLRQYzBAGOG9DHWQlJDOxqAZgxIg1NbGZkE43LQlDLuykVQtgKfDDO3SflrJjq@IWvYMWa3ZzzGRsh1BPOj@UegyST@Efd7Ni02720tD@Oj1jm6prrCU0dQ7@xKHHqI208M4ws)

-14 bytes from [Rodolvertice](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/171516/ppcg-can-triforce/171547?noredirect=1#comment414156_171547)

-1 byte by fixing a loop variable decrementation

<sub>crossed out <s>404</s> is almost still 404</sub>

Ungolfed:

```c
#define p(x)putchar(x); // save 7 bytes per putchar call (+24, -182)
#define F for // save 2 bytes per for loop (+14, -28)
int W, S, i; // W is w backup, S is s backup, i is an counter variable;
int a = ' '; // save 1 byte per space printed (+5, -8) (use a instead of 32)
int b = '/'; // save 1 byte per slash printed (+5, -6) (use b instead of 47)
int c = '\\'; // save 1 byte per backslash printed (+5, -6) (use c instead of 92)
// This isn't worth it for '\n' (-5, +3) (10), or '_' (-5, +3) (95)
int f(int w, int s) {
    W = w; // Backup w and s, as we will modify them later, 
    S = s; // but will need their original values
    for(; w != 0; --w) { // Top triangle (not the bottom line)
        for(i = W+w+s+1; i != 0; --i) // leading spaces
            putchar(' ');
        putchar('/'); // left side of triangle
        for(i = 2*w; i != 2*W; ++i) // inner spaces
            putchar(' ');
        putchar('\\'); // right side of triangle
        putchar('\n'); // newline
    }
    for(i = W+s+1; i != 0; --i)
        putchar(' '); // leading spaces for the bottom line
    putchar('/'); // left side
    for(i = 0; i != 2*W; ++i)
        putchar('_'); // the bottom line
    putchar('\\'); // right side
    for(; s-- + 1 != 0;)
        putchar('\n'); // newline after the bottom line and S empty lines
    for(w = W; w != 0; --w) { // Bottom triangles
        for(i = w; i != 0; --i)
            putchar(' '); // leading spaces
        putchar('/'); // left of left triangle
        for(i = w*2; i != 2*W; ++i)
            putchar(' '); // inside of left triangle
        putchar('\\'); // right of left triangle
        for(i = w*2+S*2; i != 0; --i)
            putchar(' '); // spaces between left and right triangles
        putchar('/');
        for(i = w*2; i != 2*W; ++i)
            putchar(' '); // inside of right triangle
        putchar('\\'); // right of right triangle
        putchar('\n'); // newline
    }
    putchar('//'); // left of left
    for(i = 0; i != 2*W; ++i)
        putchar('_'); // bottom of left triangle
    putchar('\\'); // right of left
    for(i = S*2; i != 0; --i)
        putchar(' '); // space between triangles
    putchar('/'); // left of right
    for(i = 0; i != 2*W; ++i)
        putchar('_'); // bottom of left triangle
    putchar('\\'); // right of right
}
```

Comment: #define f for   saves a few bytes

Comment: Can you not do `#define p putchar`?

Comment: @RK. If I did, then I would have to use `p(x);` instead of `p(x)`, for (+26, -6) = +20 bytes. The semicolon is included when the macro is expanded.

Comment: [284 bytes](https://tio.run/##bZDBbsIwEETPzVdEcNkltlScVggtPucDcvDZMZj6UIhwi5Gi8OthLVpRtT1Ynhnb8@R1cu/cNM23Ox8Ou7KHC/afH@7NnlhR8Z03YEUnHPrjCYK2FKQk7KHj5bAw1FIgq2tFnX5ZkdNrRR6SiDgYnSi/anWkRFImHBowVZLXKLgT2ci02SzZOG5bPuOYo8dpZcT69QtN13gH87XskzaP0vS3j8OqvZt/SfkHPxANtAv1mztO52PYlu82HCArLIfiyUMtSsUD4mFFmM1YeVCi5n2cbg "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 51 bytes

```
+‘⁶ẋ;Ɱ®Y
‘⁼þ`a”/o"”_o⁶Ṛ;ṚØ^yƊ$€©ż`j€Ḥ⁶ẋƊ}Y,@çj‘⁷ẋƊ}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/1/7UcOMR43bHu7qtn60cd2hdZFcYIE9h/clJD5qmKufrwQk4/NBSnbOsgbiwzPiKo91qTxqWnNo5dE9CVlAxsMdSyBGHOuqjdRxOLw8C2zGdojI////jf8bAwA)